# I have a cash counter with RS232 in the back of it, I want to read the data that supposed displayed on the projector

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, digital-analog-conversion

I have cash counter with RS232 in the back of it. I want to read the data that supposed displayed on the projector with RS232 to TTL convertor and arduino.

Here is all my setup

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now I

- Connect the MAX3232 TX pin to the RX Arduino pin
- and Connect the MAX3232 RX pin to the TX Arduino pin
- and the Vcc to 5V
- and MAX3232  GND to arduino  GND
- and plug the MAX3232  to the cash counter and the arduino to the pc
- and flash

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int data = Serial.read();
  if (data != -1) {
    Serial.println(data);
  }
}
```

And the output comes like this

```
50
56
48
67
49
52
48
8
10
106
13
51
56
56
76
147
48
51
12
13
83
106
51
1
13
64
10
1
49
254
254
254
254
252
254
255
```

How can I read the data from this device?

Comment: you have to determine what data is actually sent by the counter ... until you have that information available, the question is not about arduino

Comment: Use `Serial.write()` instead of `Serial.println()`. Printing interprets the data as a number (integer) into the ASCII representation, while writing sends the data unchanged. If the device sends ASCII encoded data you then will be able to read it in the serial monitor

Comment: Posting the make, model will help all of us. Also what does the instruction manual tell you?

Comment: From the labels in the pictures supplied by the OP and a some minutes with Google it appears to be a Proware Mix Value Counter STS 6000-T https://www.facebook.com/ProWare-117664076286992/videos/currency-counter-machine/760314631226329/. Some technical reference from the manufacturer would help but the interface may be proprietary and not published. It will be used at least for uploading profiles of new bank notes. Some similar machines allow you also to download the bank note details like serial numbers etc.

Comment: thank u i send message to them i hope the can help me with any info about this problem  @6v6gt

Comment: there is no information about the model till now i dont have any useful info to share :( @Gil